# Error invoking chaincode "Error: unknown flag: --peerAddresses" Hyperledger Fabric first-network tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been roughly following http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#troubleshoot to create my first network, and have executed steps involving installing, istantiating, querying a chaincode. However, I get the following error while invoking chaincode.

```
root@5a0be253ef6e:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C testhimani123456 -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
Error: unknown flag: --peerAddresses
Usage:
  peer chaincode invoke [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string   The channel on which this command should be executed
  -c, --ctor string        Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -n, --name string        Name of the chaincode

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --transient string                    Transient map of arguments in JSON encoding
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

I have ignored the part concerning environment variables. [image] I was confused as to where to include it. I tried adding the fields that were absent in *docker-compose-base.yaml* file, but it gave me errors while running `docker exec -it cli bash` command, saying that there is no container for cli. So i decided to go with the original file, completely ignoring the step.

Answer (score 1):

(finally know how to use this) Actually found the solution thanks to a friend.

The "peer chaincode invoke " doesn't have the flag "peerAddresses". The code given on the Hyperledger fabric tutorial documentation might be outdated or incorrect.

This can be seen in the Reference documentation : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peerchaincode.html

So removing peerAddresses and writing something like this might solve the error.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem  -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
```

Comment: No, its not the right way to ask a question related to main question. You need to post a newer one or try to solve from the solution you get on searching

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by changing chaincode instantiation by changing "and" to "or".
Since I had skipped the environment variables step, default was peer0.org1 (i.e. org1MSP). Nothing was set for org2MSP. Thus it was in no position to award permissions in the first place.

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```